# Can't install FOSCommentBundle with Symfony 2.3.7

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3, foscommentbundle

I'm having dependency issues installing with Symfony 2.3.7.  This is a completely new install of Symfony, downloaded 2.3.7 without Vendors zip.  Run composer update for the initial install.  Then added the comment bundle to composer.json and run composer update again.

The require section of composer.json,

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "2.0.5"
},
```

And the error from 'php composer.phar update'

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v2.3.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.3
    - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle 2.0.5 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle[v2.0.5].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.1
    - friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle v2.0.5 requires symfony/symfony >=2.1,<2.3-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.10].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.12].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.13].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.3].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.4].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.8].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.10].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.3].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.8].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.9].
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 2.3.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.2, v2.3.3, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7].
```

Comment: I've also tried 2.0.4 and get a JMS serilizer dependancy issue.  friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle v2.0.4 requires jms/serializer 1.0.*@dev -> no matching package found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem here, you have got symfony > 2.3, but comments require < 2.3

```
friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle v2.0.5 requires symfony/symfony >=2.1,<2.3-dev
```

Try to install [this version](https://packagist.org/packages/friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle#dev-master) of comments

```
"friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "2.0.*@dev"
```

with this flag in *composer.json*(not required, force all dependencies to dev last dev versions)

```
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

Comment: the `minimum-stability` option in composer sets the minimum stability for **all** packages. This is absolutely not recommended as it can easily break your application. Adding all unstable packages (and their unstable dependencies in case) to the `require` array with the `@dev`, `@alpha`, `@beta` or `@RC` flag is a far better practice!

Comment: 2.0.*@dev seems to be working today.  Its pulling dev-master correctly instead of 2.0.4 which it was doing the other day.

Comment: "minimum-stability": "dev", isn't really an option.  Forcing dev over all packages isn't ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The first 2 lines explain everything:

> friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle v2.0.4 requires jms/serializer 1.0.*@dev -> no matching package found.

Looking at your composer,json, you have 0.13.*@dev, not 1.0.*@dev

> symfony/framework-bundle 2.0.7 requires symfony/translator 2.0.7 -> no matching package found.

Looking at your composer.json, you have installed 2.3.*, not 2.0.

I think you try to install an old version of the foscommentbundle and an old version of the jms serializer bundle.

Comment: 1.0.@dev Doesn't exist. well I can't find the tag anyway.  I've seen a few places saying this.  I've changed the json file to "jms/serializer": "*@dev",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "*@dev", now and still get the error.

Comment: 2.3.7 is installed, the next line reads, Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v2.3.7

Comment: @shapeshifter Yes, this package needs symfony 2.0. that's why I said you need to find a new version of this bundle

Answer (score -1):

remove the line "jms/serializer-bundle": "1.0.@dev"
and run *composer update*.
This removes any old version of the serializer.
After that you can later add 
"jms/serializer-bundle": "0.13.*@dev"
if you want.